# question in product

Tags: arithmetic

can any expert just check my solution

You bought a car for $\$2500$ down and made payments of $\$299.50$ each month for $36$ months.
(a) Find the amount of the payments over the $36$ months.
(b) Find the total cost of the car.

I have tried to solve please check it 
for

part (a) $299.50 * 36= 10782$

part (b) $10782+2500= 13282$

also,another question

Use a calculator to multiply. Then use estimation to determine whether the product you calculated is reasonable $85.3 ✕  7.7$

I have tried to solve please check it

calculated $656.81$

estimated $720$

thank you very much

sorry for asking simple questions but this question I need them

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Comment: that means my answer is correct? thank you

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I Think the question lacks information to give a proper answer. Nothing says that the payments corresponds to the actual cost of the car.

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitry said, your calculations are correct.

Regarding the second question, your estimation is reasonable and your calculation is correct. If you would ever like to ask another question, please don't add it onto the end of an existing question, but ask a new question.